# Users property from IdentityRole moved or deleted on ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In the previous version I was able to feed my model the number of Users from the Identity package, specifically IdentityRole:

```
        model = roleManager.Roles.Select(r => new ApplicationRoleListviewModel
        {
            RoleName = r.Name,
            Id = r.Id,
            Description = r.Description,
            NumberOfUsers = r.Users.Count
        }).ToList();
```

Now there is an error mentioning that Users is not defined. Was this property deleted or moved?

Name and Id is extracted from:

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
{
    public class IdentityRole<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
  {
    public IdentityRole();
    public IdentityRole(string roleName);
    public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string NormalizedName { get; set; }
    public virtual string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }
    public override string ToString();
  }
}
```

Description property is a property defined by me on this project.

Thanks

Comment: Seems that navigation property was [removed](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/commit/e6f3ebf5810c793edc6f3b4ca3438194786b86a2#diff-3ab81be1e74c2ad40e20e2602d883584L88) for some reason while some refactoring was going on. My guess was that it was preparation for making roles optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the navigation properties were removed by Microsoft, you're going to have to put them back in yourself. The easiest way to do that would be to create your own role class, for example:

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; } = new List<Users>();
}
```

And then change your context to use this class instead of the default.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer. When you say to change the context, that would be editing the Startup class, especifically this line? services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()

Comment: That's one of them yes, but if you already have that, it looks like your mostly there, just add the above line to your `ApplicationRole` class.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks, but when adding that line I'm getting an error: *You can not implicitly convert the type 'System.Collections.Generic.List <Users>' into 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection <Application.Models.User>'. An explicit conversion already exists (check if a conversion is missing)*

Comment: Well you need to replace `User` with your user class, perhaps `ApplicationUser`?

Comment: oh, I understand now. Sometimes I miss when generic names are used to be replaced with one owns project. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Although it doesn't answer your specific `IdentityRole` problem, there is a section in [Migrating Authentication and Identity to ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x#add-identityuser-poco-navigation-properties) that states:

> The Entity Framework Core navigation properties of the base IdentityUser POCO (Plain Old CLR Object) have been removed.

Given that the latest version of [`IdentityRole`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores/IdentityRole.cs) does not have the `Users` navigation property as you pointed out, it looks like you would need to add it back manually if you need it.